# How to draw a line with WicketStuff OpenLayers3

Tags: line, openlayers-3, wicketstuff

I'd like to use WicketStuff OpenLayers3 library to draw simple 'route' line
with some interactive markers, based on some GeoJson input.

I found sites like:
http://tomcat.nervestaple.com/openlayers3-examples-6.0-SNAPSHOT/index
 , but they show no example how to draw a line.

Of course I'm able to draw lines and markers with pure JavaScript OL3 library,
but the point is to use WicketStuff as my existing application is using it.

At the moment of writing this question (2015-05-28) WS OL3 library does not support OL3 3.5.0, as I discussed it with WS team member here:
https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/issues/404 , so the target OL3 library should be 3.2.0 and Wicket 6.

Comment: Did you find any solution?